# Is it possible to decorate the Google Calendar or GMail UIs using Google Apps Script?

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script

When I heard about Google Apps Script, I thought that, among other things, it allowed you to add or change UI elements in the existing Google Apps as the Labs extensions do.  Was that just a misunderstanding or would it be possible to make additions/changes to Google Calendar or GMail?  I was thinking of changing the create/edit event window in Google Calendar to support auto-complete in the "Where" field, drawing on addresses in a user's contacts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not currently possible to do this with Apps Script. You can, however, create custom menus in Google Spreadsheets: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_spreadsheet#addMenu